# arima$residuals does not contain dates

Tags: r, arima

Plotting my fitted arima() function of the residuals I don't get the index(dates) on the x-axis. Searching for an answer the common issue is that one might want dates for the forecast as well. I just want it for the fitted residuals, which does not seem to have been raised as a problem before.

Here are the first six lines of my data set:

```
structure(c(-8.810021, 1.45281, -9.051401, 4.628075, -1.774445, 
-5.25055, -4.08219945, -0.17376199, 1.32681098, 3.7986923, -0.03966156, 
0.1651528, -3.989133, 0.1787311, -1.620197, 5.645238, 0.3424661, 
-1.203798, -3.813763, -2.360084, 1.391327, 7.280618, -1.841673, 
-1.498155), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(946944000, 
947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 947548800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(6L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("AAPL", "GE", "SPY", "WMT")))
```

For the data of SPY I've found a model I want to continue with by using arima():

```
fitSPY<-arima(SMinexts[,"SPY"],order = c(1,0,3))
```

I can use several functions to plot the residuals. Here are two:

```
checkresiduals(fitSPY)
plot(fitSPY)
```

My problem is, that I don't get the dates on the x-axis when plotting the residuals as I have seen elsewhere, like here for example: https://otexts.com/fpp2/regarima.html.

From str of fitSPY I guess the problem is that the time series dates are registered as [1-4024] instead od the dates of the data set. I just don't know how to fix this.

```
> str(fitSPY)
List of 14
 $ coef     : Named num [1:5] -0.9179 0.8524 -0.1318 -0.0784 0.0165
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "ar1" "ma1" "ma2" "ma3" ...
 $ sigma2   : num 1.6
 $ var.coef : num [1:5, 1:5] 2.75e-03 -2.72e-03 1.78e-04 2.24e-05 2.04e-07 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "ar1" "ma1" "ma2" "ma3" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "ar1" "ma1" "ma2" "ma3" ...
 $ mask     : logi [1:5] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 $ loglik   : num -6657
 $ aic      : num 13326
 $ arma     : int [1:7] 1 3 0 0 1 0 0
 $ residuals: Time-Series [1:4024] from 1 to 4024: -3.9849 -0.0787 -1.9213 5.4402 0.5981 ...
 $ call     : language arima(x = SMinexts[, "SPY"], order = c(1, 0, 3))
 $ series   : chr "SMinexts[, \"SPY\"]"
 $ code     : int 1
 $ n.cond   : int 0
 $ nobs     : int 4024
 $ model    :List of 10
  ..$ phi  : num -0.918
  ..$ theta: num [1:3] 0.8524 -0.1318 -0.0784
  ..$ Delta: num(0) 
  ..$ Z    : num [1:4] 1 0 0 0
  ..$ a    : num [1:4] -1.0219 -0.8423 0.1836 0.0782
  ..$ P    : num [1:4, 1:4] 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ T    : num [1:4, 1:4] -0.918 0 0 0 1 ...
  ..$ V    : num [1:4, 1:4] 1 0.8524 -0.1318 -0.0784 0.8524 ...
  ..$ h    : num 0
  ..$ Pn   : num [1:4, 1:4] 1 0.8524 -0.1318 -0.0784 0.8524 ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "Arima"
```

Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make residuals as an xts object with the index from the original data and plot.

```
resid <- xts(fitSPY$residuals, index(SMinexts))
plot(resid, observation.based =TRUE, yaxis.right = FALSE)
```

[image]

You can also coerce the index into the resuduals in the list

```
fitSPY$residuals <- xts(fitSPY$residuals, index(SMinexts))
```